application.properties: unused properties
So I just used the spring boot initializr to setup up the project with postgresql driver, spring web, and jpa using maven and java 17, then I jump straight into the application.properties and configure the basics. but then for all the projects up until now i get unused property:
# Database connection settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your_database_name
spring.datasource.username=your_username
spring.datasource.password=your_password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
How do i fix this
Im trying ot connect to the database postgresql

What properties are unused according to your IDE? What are the dependencies you are using?

This is a normal situation with IDE like IntelliJ. You can simply ignore this warning.

if you want to connect to the postgreSQL, you must specify this properties. Not sure which properties are unused.
I can share my properties for connection to the PostgreSQL/TimescaleDB
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:postgres}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true

Username, password, and URL I've set via environment variables.
